# Functional form of the drive of IBMQ machines

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-control

I am trying to apply some ML techniques to try and find out pulse sequences to implement different kinds of gates using Qiskit Pulse. For the ML part, it is necessary for me to know the Hamiltonian of the IBMQ system that is being used to simulate the evolution of the qubit in order to find fidelity with respect to target states.

I used the `backed.configuration()` to get the Hamiltonian and the parameters. To test if   the stuff is working alright I used a simple constant amplitude pulse to check and compare if the Hamiltonian I simulate matched with what was going on in an actual system. And lo! It was way off mark. What I am particularly concerned about is if I input a list of complex numbers to the `pulse.play()` function how is it implemented on the system? I had been assuming that the implementation is:

```
Drive_Hamiltonian = (real(amplitude_value) * cos (omega_d * t) + imaginary(amplitude_value) * sin(omega_d * t)) * Sigma_x
```

If the drive is alright I am hoping to get any hints and suggestions as to where to look for to actually get the exact implementation of the Hamiltonian on the actual system? I have tried the Qiskit Pulse documentation and Qiskit textbook but neither seem to have any suggestions on this besides looking up on `backend.configuration()`.